# Arithmetic operation in terminal from an output

Tags: command-line, terminal, text-formatting, dnf, arithmetic

I want to print the lines of updates via this command

`dnf check-update --refresh --q --downloadonly | wc -l`

However during the output there occurs a blank line which means the **true** update number is will be less than 1 from the output of the above command.

How can I subtract 1 from the above command, in **a one line command** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `wc -l` by `grep -c .` to skip the blank line:

```
dnf check-update --refresh --q --downloadonly | grep -c .
```

or

```
dnf check-update --refresh --q --downloadonly | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l
```

or if you insist to do arithmetic:

```
printf '%s\n' $(( $(dnf check-update --refresh --q --downloadonly | wc -l) -1))
```

`$((...))` is an arithmetic substitution. After doing the arithmetic, the whole thing is replaced by the value of the expression. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression.